# Not getting the required date

Tags: php, datetime

I want to calculate the difference between date using date_diff(), whose 1st parameter is saved data in database and the 2nd parameter is today's date. The $pro_deadline is coming from database and is of type text (format yyyy-mm-dd), so I converted it into time using strtotime(). But in the end I'm getting "
Warning
: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given"

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
echo $today;
$end = strtotime($pro_deadline);
$end_line = date("Y-m-d",$end);
echo $end_line;
$diff = date_diff($end_line,$today);
echo $diff;
```

Comment: date returns string, not date

Comment: then I should not use the date function for the $end?

Comment: You need to generate `DateTime` objects, see [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for examples.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just return the difference in your SQL query, something like: `SELECT DATEDIFF(date_column, CURDATE()) FROM my_table;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

```
date_diff — Alias of DateTime::diff()
```

so the perameters to date_diff should be DateTimeInterface types.

i would try

```
<?php

$today = date("Y-m-d");
echo $today."            ";
$today = date_create($today);
$pro_deadline = '10-15-18';
$end = strtotime($pro_deadline);
$end_line = date_create(date("Y-m-d",$end));
$diff = date_diff($end_line,$today);
echo $diff->format('%a');
echo " days apart";
?>
```

the date_create() function is an alias of the DateTime constructor. 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

this creates an interface for the date/time that the date_diff() function can interpret. then date_diff() returns a DateInterval object

http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

the DateInterval object has a format method

http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

that can return the date in a sting for you.

Hope this explanation helps!

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, `date_diff` expects [DateTimeInterface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) parameters. `strtotime` returns a timestamp as an integer, which it can't work with.

Instead of creating timestamps, you can pass your deadline to the `DateTime` constructor, along with another version that'll default to now:

```
$today = new DateTime;
$end = new DateTime($pro_deadline);
```

and then pass these two objects to `date_diff`, and use the [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method to display the number of days (assuming this is your desired output):

```
$diff = date_diff($today,$end);
echo $diff->format('%a');
```

See https://3v4l.org/QVkad for a full example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want a difference between a date in a database and today's date, just do it in the database directly.  You didn't specify which DB, but, for example in MySQL you'd do something like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(some_field, now()) FROM ...
```

If you insist on doing it in PHP, then don't use `strtotime` but use `DateTime` object:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime($pro_deadline);
$diff = $end.diff($today)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date()` function returns a simple string, but the date_diff() function expects a date *object*.

You can do it all much more simply with the functions in the `DateTime` class:

```
$pro_deadline = "2018-09-01";
$today = new DateTime();
$end = new DateTime($pro_deadline);
$interval = $end->diff($today);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

This example outputs `+25 days` [Click here for Runnable Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09c8688ce1ef0e664a2f01624017950556fa4783)

Further examples of the diff() function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)